Drush 13.3.3.0 does not show admin commands although database connections seems to be working
Simple admin commands like "drush en" and "drush cc" result in
 "command pm (or cc) was not found. Drush was unable to query your database. As a result, many commands are unavailable."

"drush status" works fine and shows the correct info.
"drush (php version 8.3.14, the right site info, etc). "drush sqlc" connects to my site's database (show tables shows the correct info).
"drush cc --debug" shows:
Exception trace:
  at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:233
 Drush\Application->bootstrapAndFind() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:185
 Drush\Application->find() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:266
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:175
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:110
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:40
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:140
 include() at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal10/vendor/bin/drush.php:120

With "drush en mymodule" I expected the command to be executed. Via the site and admin account. I can do the work but drush should be able to do this too.

Switch to DDEV, ditch XAMPP

Drush was installed using "composer require drush/drush". Maybe I should switch to DDEV, however so far (the last 15 years XAMPP worked fine too). I am in the process converting my website from Drupal 6 to Drupal 10, so indeed it might be time for a switch to DDEV too. By the way I working on a MacBook Air at the moment.

I also work on an MBA. You will not regret switching to DDEV. There's also a quickstart guide for Drupal 6/7: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#drupal-drupal-67. I recommend you use OrbStack as Docker provider.

I used the advice and moved to DDEV.  Drush works fine too. So far I used "ddev launch". In OrbStack I see containers running. I can access my site. Even use phpmyadmin. All working fine. Thanks for the advice
